# Intel NIC not showing up on new install of debian

Tags: network-interface, kernel-modules

I'm trying to install this NIC:
`Intel E10G42BT X520-T2 10Gigabit Ethernet Card 10Gbps PCI Express x8 2 x RJ45`

Onto a server running proxmox:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.74-1-pve
```

I can see the device shows up when I run `lspci -v`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0001 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Device 1b52:151c
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at 70200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
        I/O ports at 5020 [disabled] [size=32]
        Memory at 70404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=64 Masked-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 68-05-ca-ff-ff-11-6e-3a
        Capabilities: [150] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        Capabilities: [160] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)

01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0001 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Device 1b52:151c
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at 70000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [disabled] [size=32]
        Memory at 70400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=64 Masked-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 68-05-ca-ff-ff-11-6e-3a
        Capabilities: [150] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        Capabilities: [160] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
```

but I noticed that it doesn't specify a kernel module

I believe I have the right modules installed, and loaded using `modprobe`

```
root@pve1:~# modinfo ixgbe
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.74-1-pve/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko
license:        GPL v2
description:    Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     3F8E828513678E6322F58DC
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015AEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ACsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ADsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ABsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015B0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015AAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015D1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001563sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001560sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001557sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001558sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001528sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000151Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001529sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000152Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001514sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001507sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001517sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001508sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010ECsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio,dca,xfrm_algo
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ixgbe
vermagic:       5.15.74-1-pve SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_vfs:Maximum number of virtual functions to allocate per physical function - default is zero and maximum value is 63. (Deprecated) (uint)
parm:           allow_unsupported_sfp:Allow unsupported and untested SFP+ modules on 82599-based adapters (uint)
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
```

The network interface doesn't show up in `ip a`

```
root@pve1:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:6b:00:08:da:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:6b:00:08:da:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.200/24 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9e6b:ff:fe08:da65/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm pretty new to linux/setting up drivers on it, is there some other step I'm missing for associating the ixgbe module with the device?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for missing firmware

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as reported (and solved) [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1115067/505837) where a user had the same problem with a X520-DA2 card. The subvendor id "0001" in "Intel Corporation Device 0001" looks wrong. Same problem on the proxmox forum with [X-520-T2 not getting detected](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/proxmox-6-1-intel-x-520-t2-not-getting-detected.67094/). Can you bring up the interface
with `modprobe ixgbe; echo 8086 0001 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbe/new_id`?

Comment: An update on this - It certainly seems like I'm having the same issue as those folks.  I am able to force the Intel driver to be used by setting the new_id values, however from that thread, that is a temporary solution after which they use `ethtool` to flash the correct vendor/device IDs to the EEPROM. 

The linked case where the user solved the issue was for a X-520-DA2 card (which is sfp) which seems to have better documentation around the device IDs.  I raised a support ticket with Intel if they can help me with getting the correct values, however otherwise Ill be returning the card.